# apache2 config file not working for 2nd virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2

My apache2 config file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
)  doesn't work as I expect.

I want http://flowerchildevents.com/ to map to /home/webuser/helloworld/htdocs/
and
 www.searchstream.co/ to map to /var/www/html

however both sites map to /var/www/html

any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName www.searchstream.co
    <directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/webuser/helloworld/htdocs/
        ServerName www.flowerchildevents.com
        ServerAlias *.flowerchildevents.com
    <directory /home/webuser/helloworld/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you have actually never told the VirtualHost in question that it should be aware of the name *flowerchildevents.com*. Try adding that explicitly as a ServerAlias.